# make a string (with spaces) of a path usable for rm

Tags: linux, bash, path

I have an array (pfad) containing a filepath as a string f.e. (got it with `tree` and some `sed` stuff)

```
/media/usb1/Filme/Jersey\ Boys\ (2014)/review.txt
```

I want to delete this file:

```
rm ${pfad[$j]}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because we don't have the correct format to access directorys with spaces. I figured out it should be like this:

```
rm /media/usb1/Filme/Jersey\ Boys\ \(2014\)/review.txt
```

So I am missing '\' twice. once in front of "(" and once behind "2014".
How can I adjust this?

I guess it's possible to replace `(2014)` with `\(2014\)` via `sed`, but that is pretty sloppy and I I had to do it for every year.

If there is a better way to get the absolute full path (and size) of every file in a directory and its subfolders in two (or one) arrays, I woud like to learn. I am free to use perl / ruby or what ever Raspbian has to offer. (Would be nice if it is kinda ressource friendly.)
Thanks for reading.

EDIT (my) workaround:

use `tree -N` it creates the output without " \ ". after that put the variable (array) as mentioned in the comments in "$variable".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly bothers you.

Comment: I can't remove the review.txt because `rm ${pfad[$j]}` doesn't work.

Comment: I need to get `rm ${pfad[$j]}` working with the given value of f.e. `/media/usb1/Filme/Jersey\ Boys\ (2014)/review.txt`. I need to remove multiple files with specific size and a specific name etc. in different folders. I have multiple if conditions, if they are fine I just want to `rm ${pfad[$j]}`. I can't adjust every filepath by hand.

Comment: @user3715758 quote the variable...

Comment: I found another solution but thank you guys.

Comment: @user3715758 post it here; may be useful for someone in the feature.

Comment: You should not parse the output of `tree` or `ls` in the first place. Use globs instead.